# Testing symmetry on symmetric matrix fails

Tags: r

I have a symmetric matrix (4x4) in memory.  Unfortunately, sum( originalMatrix != t( originalMatrix ) ) = 6.  So I dput that matrix and read it back into memory.  Now sum( dputMatrix!= t( dputMatrix) ) = 0.  How is that possible and how can I test for symmetry with my in-memory matrix?

```
originalMatrix = ...
sum( originalMatrix != t( originalMatrix ) )  # results in 6
dput( originalMatrix )
dputMatrix = structure(c(0.00117771346463494, -1.57864028664711e-05, 0.000293652924987303, 
-9.85387333663002e-05, -1.57864028664711e-05, 0.000194782042576016, 
6.9133672862693e-05, 4.23792732612071e-05, 0.000293652924987303, 
6.9133672862693e-05, 0.00046216043028767, 2.70172523991749e-05, 
-9.85387333663002e-05, 4.23792732612071e-05, 2.70172523991749e-05, 
0.00017694896679169), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a00088630", 
"a0091n", "a01010", "a01307810"), c("a00088630", "a0091n", "a01010", 
"a01307810")))
sum( dputMatrix != t( dputMatrix ) )  # results in 0!!!
```

Comment: I found that all.equal returns TRUE for both originalMatrix and the dputMatrix tests

Comment: Looks like R FAQ 7.31 applies. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html

Comment: I was aware of this issue, but couldn't make sense of why the dput version worked.  Thanks for the pointer to the FAQ!  I think this statement explains it: "...unless they have been computed by the same algorithm".  The dput version gives R the opportunity to read the numbers into memory in the exact same way I guess.

Comment: Yeah, dput is only writing to a low precision. Use save() for writing R objects out exactly.

Comment: thanks!  Could you post your two comments as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a manifestation of FAQ 7.31. Note that if you want to save R objects to full precision you should use save().

Tick please!

Comment: Is there a way to dump R objects at high precision, e.g. for lossless translation to another program?

Comment: writeBin can save floating point data using the internal binary representation. You could read this back into a C program, but there may be issues with endianity.