# Do you reassign == and != to isTRUE( all.equal() )?

Tags: r

A [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663311/testing-symmetry-on-symmetric-matrix-fails) prompted me to post this question.  It would seem like a best-practice to reassign `==` to `isTRUE(all.equal())` ( and `!=` to `!isTRUE(all.equal())`.  I'm wondering if others do this in practice?  I just realized that I use `==` and `!=` to do numeric equality throughout my codebase.  My first reaction was that I need to do a full-scrub and convert to `all.equal`.  But in fact, everytime I use `==` and `!=` I want to test equality (regardless of the datatype).  In fact, I'm not sure what these operations would test for other than equality.  I'm sure I'm missing some concept here.  Can someone enlighten me?  The only argument I see against this approach is that in some cases two non-identical numbers will appear to be identical because of the tolerance of `all.equal`.  But we're told that two numbers that are in fact identical might not pass `identical()` because of how they are are stored in memory.  So really what's the point of not defaulting to `all.equal`?

Comment: That seemed like such a strange thing to do, then I read the Note in the Comparison help page: "Do not use == and != for tests, such as in if expressions, where you must get a single TRUE or FALSE. Unless you are absolutely sure that nothing unusual can happen, you should use the identical function instead." So maybe it is not that absurd an idea.

Comment: I'm going to say no, you shouldn't. Use `identical` instead, and keep `==` around for vectorized comparisons when subsetting.

Comment: If you start overloading  common operators, your code will be seriously non-portable.  Far better to learn what each operator or function does and use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: joran - but identical doesn't always work.  From the R FAQ: "As a result, two floating point numbers will not reliably be equal unless they have been computed by the same algorithm, and not always even then".  So basically this is saying that identical will fail even if two numbers are the same!

Comment: @SFun28 True, but that's simply a floating point issue that you'll run into anywhere. Still better not to mask `==`. Why define new ones, `===` and `!==` instead using `isTRUE` and `all.equal`?

Comment: joran - I agree that masking is not a great solution.  Its a just a bummer because == and != is intuitive but requires caution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @joran alluded to, you'll run into floating point issues with `==` and `!=` in pretty much any other language too. One important aspect of them in R is the vectorization part.

It would be much better to define a new function `almostEqual`, `fuzzyEqual` or similar. It is unfortunate that there is no such base function. `all.equal` isn't very efficient since it handles all kinds of objects and returns a **string** describing the difference when mostly you just want `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Here's an example of such a function. It's vectorized like `==`.

```
almostEqual <- function(x, y, tolerance=1e-8) {
  diff <- abs(x - y)
  mag <- pmax( abs(x), abs(y) )
  ifelse( mag > tolerance, diff/mag <= tolerance, diff <= tolerance)
}

almostEqual(1, c(1+1e-8, 1+2e-8)) # [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

...it is around 2x faster than `all.equal` for scalar values, and much faster with vectors.

```
x <- 1
y <- 1+1e-8
system.time(for(i in 1:1e4) almostEqual(x, y)) # 0.44 seconds
system.time(for(i in 1:1e4) all.equal(x, y))   # 0.93 seconds
```

Comment: Tommy - after some testing I think there is a bug in this function.  Consider:   matrixa = round( matrix( rnorm( 9 ) , nrow = 3 , ncol = 3 ) , 6 )
matrixb = matrixa - .001
almostEqual( matrixa , matrixb , tolerance = .001 )

Comment: Even this produces FALSE sometimes: almostEqual( matrixa , matrixb , tolerance = .01 )

Comment: @SFun28 - I think the code is correct. Try `all.equal` instead and you also get non-TRUE. It's because it's a RELATIVE tolerance. `rnorm` can  give big (3.5) or small (0.0003) numbers, but your error that you add to matrixb is always `0.001`. Try `matrixb <- matrixa*1.001` instead.