# Relative error between two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Given two float matrices in R, I would like to get the relative error between every entry, and then among all errors search the max of all of them and compare it against 10%, i.e. `MAX_ERROR <= 10%`

I know that the raltive error is (for each entry):

```
|v_ij(MATRIX1) - v_ij(MATRIX2)| / | v_ij(MATRIX1)|
```

How to do this in `R`, avoiding a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to handle cases where the matrix has zeroes in it (which otherwise leads to division by zero), this answer has some solutions: [Do you reassign == and != to isTRUE( all.equal() )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664017/do-you-reassign-and-to-istrue-all-equal/7667703#7667703)

A slight modification of the `almostEqual` function I suggested there would yield:

```
relativeError <- function(x, y, tolerance=1e-8) {
  diff <- abs(x - y)
  mag <- pmax( abs(x), abs(y) )
  ifelse( mag > tolerance, diff/mag, diff)
}

m1 <- cbind(c(0,1), c(1,1))
m2 <- cbind(c(0,1), c(1,1.11)) 
any(relativeError(m1, m2) > 0.01) # TRUE

# Building on @DWin's answer:
which(relativeError(m1, m2) > 0.01, arr.ind=TRUE) # 2 2
```

Note that this calculates the relative error slightly differently than your definition: it's symmetric and handles small values - and it's a bit slower because of it...

Comment: Nice work. We are approaching a bullet-proof, yet flexible answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you wnat to identify which elements fail that test then try this:

```
over_err <- which( abs(MATRIX1-MATRIX2)/abs(MATRIX1) > 0.1, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

If you want to dispaly a list of indices and values in MATRIX1 that satisfy (or fail to satisfy) that condition then:

```
cbind(over_err, MATRIX1[over_err])
```

Comment: And if you want to order them, then just use `out <- cbind(over_err, values = MATRIX1[over_err])` and `out[order(values, decreasing = T),]`. :-)

Comment: Good one: And if you just wanted the "top five", you could then use: `out[order(values, decreasing = T),][1:5]`

Comment: Good! :-) But if there is less then 5, you get NAs. Maybe `head(out[...], 5)` would be better (although not that elegant!).

Comment: +1 again. Perhaps `out[order(values, decreasing = T),][ 1:max(NROW(out), 5) ]`

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
maxerr <- max(abs((a - b) / a))
```

where `a` and `b` are the two matrices. To convert the result to percentage, multiply by `100`.

Answer (score 1):

If  the Exact matrix  M_exact and the approximated matrix is M_app; then using Mathematica, the percentage error can be calculated as

```
error(%) = 100(Norm[M_app - M_exact]/Norm[M_exact])
```

To check the relative error in matrix element

```
Relative_error = (Abs[M_app - M_exact])/Abs[M_exact]
```

For further detail:
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node75.html