# Incorrect logical return for simple sequence

Tags: r

Here is some basic code and its output. I really can't say anything more than a logical test for a sequence containing 1.2 is giving an inaccurate result. It is working for many other values.

```
# Incorrect
> seq(0.5, 1.5, by=0.05) == 1.2
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Correct
> seq(0.5, 1.5, by=0.05) == 1.15
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Correct
> seq(0.5, 1.5, by=0.05) == 1.25
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Correct
> seq(0.5, 1.5, by=0.05) == 1.3
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I tried testing all the values using the following, which does not reproduce the bug:

```
> sapply(seq(0.5, 1.5, by=0.05), function(x){sum(seq(0.5, 1.5, by=0.05) == x)})
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I'm using R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30), Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit).

Comment: This is not a bug, it's the consequence of using floating point aritmetic to represent  numbers.  You should use `all.equal` instead of `==` to test for equality.  This question has been asked a few times on SO - I shall attempt to find them and post links.

Comment: That was my guess. But I assumed that the same issue would arise for other values, no? Also, `all.equal` won't work here because I want to find the value that is equal to 1.2 (I had this test inside of `which()`).

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7664017/602276, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3395696/602276

Comment: It's also in the R-FAQ. You may want to read the whole document. It should save you some time (and maybe embarrassment) in the long run.

Comment: You can create a vectorized version of `all.equal` using `Vectorize`, and then `which(all.equal.vec(...) == TRUE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can duplicate what all.equal is doing by writing a comparison function of your own:

```
is.nearenough=function(x,y,tol=.Machine$double.eps^0.5){
  abs(x-y)<tol
}
```

then you can do which(is.nearenough(s,1.2)) where s is your sequence. You may need to tweak the tolerance for your application.