# Is there a bug in `match' in R?

Tags: r

How is this possible:

```
> match(1.68, seq(0.01,10, by = .01))
[1] 168
> match(1.67, seq(0.01,10, by = .01))
[1] NA
```

Does the R function `match` have a bug in it?

Comment: Looks like a floating point precision issue, but I don't know enough about how R deals with such things to go deeper

Comment: R FAQ 7.31 http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: Identical to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7778569/602276

Comment: It is certainly similar underlying problem, but getting a correct index with match is a bit different.

Comment: can we have an "R FAQ 7.31" tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this type of problem, I prefer the solution described by Chambers in his book 'Software for Data Analysis':

```
match(1.68, seq(1, 1000, by = 1)/100)
# [1] 168
match(1.67, seq(1, 1000, by = 1)/100)
# [1] 167
```

(It works because there are no floating point issues involved in producing a sequence of integers.  The rounding only occurs upon division by 100, and matches the rounding produced by converting the typed number `1.67` to binary.)

This solution has the virtue of **not** finding a match for a number like `1.6744`, which is clearly not in the sequence `0.10, 0.11, 0.12, ..., 9.98, 9.99, 10.00`:

```
match(1.6744, seq(1,1000, by = 1)/100)
# [1] NA                               ## Just as I'd like it!
```

Comment: On re-reading DWin's comment, I see that it mentions this tangentially in the last sentence.  I'll leave this amplified version of that comment in case it's as useful to others as it has been to me.

Answer (score 7):

Typical R-FAQ 7.31 problem. Not a bug.  To avoid this common user error, use instead the function findInterval and fuzz the boundaries down a bit. (or do your selections on integer sequences.)

```
> findInterval(1.69, seq(0.01,10, by = .01))
[1] 169
> findInterval(1.69, seq(0.01,10, by = .01)-.0001)
[1] 169
> findInterval(1.68, seq(0.01,10, by = .01)-.0001)
[1] 168
> findInterval(1.67, seq(0.01,10, by = .01)-.0001)
[1] 167
> findInterval(1.66, seq(0.01,10, by = .01)-.0001)
[1] 166
```