# Check whether vector in R is sequential?

Tags: r, sequence

How can I check whether an integer vector is "sequential", i.e. that the difference between subsequent elements is exactly one. I feel like I am missing something like "is.sequential"

Here's my own function:

```
is.sequential <- function(x){
    all(diff(x) == rep(1,length(x)-1))
}
```

Comment: So 2:5 is considered a sequence but 5:2 is not?

Comment: ...and what about `c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)` and sequences with rounding errors?

Comment: @Tommy. Good points. In my case only integers are relevant, no decimals. At the moment I haven't thought much about backwards sequence, but I admit that could be interesting, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for `rep` since 1 will be recicled:

Edited to allow 5:2 as true

```
is.sequential <- function(x){
  all(abs(diff(x)) == 1)
}
```

To allow for diferent sequences

```
is.sequential <- function(x){
 all(diff(x) == diff(x)[1])
}
```

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : And beware "all.equal" vs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7667703/662787 :-)

Comment: @Tommy: since I commented there as well, I think you just put us into an infinite loop ~_*

Comment: And, while this may be desired, it should be noted that with this definition `is.sequential(c(1, 2, 1, 2)) -> T`

Comment: @shujaa That only happens with the first definition

Answer (score 2):

So, @Iselzer has a fine answer. There are still some corner cases though: rounding errors and starting value. Here's a version that allows rounding errors but checks that the first value is (almost) an integer.

```
is.sequential <- function(x, eps=1e-8) {
  if (length(x) && isTRUE(abs(x[1] - floor(x[1])) < eps)) {
     all(abs(diff(x)-1) < eps)
  } else {
    FALSE
  }
}

is.sequential(2:5) # TRUE

is.sequential(5:2) # FALSE

# Handle rounding errors?
x <- ((1:10)^0.5)^2
is.sequential(x) # TRUE

# Does the sequence need to start on an integer?
x <- c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5)
is.sequential(x) # FALSE

# Is an empty vector a sequence?
is.sequential(numeric(0)) # FALSE

# What about NAs?
is.sequential(c(NA, 1)) # FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old by now, but in certain circumstances it is actually quite useful to know whether a vector is sequential.

Both of the OP answers are quite good, but as mentioned by Tommy the accepted answer has some flaws. It seems natural that a 'sequence' is any 'sequence of numbers, which are equally spaced'. This would include negative sequences, sequences with a starting value outside different from 0 or 1, and so forth.

A very diverse and **safe** implementation is given below, which accounts for

1. negative values (-3 to 1) and negative directions (3 to 1)
2. sequences with none integer steps (3.5, 3.6, 3.7...)
3. wrong input types such as infinite values, NA and NAN values, data.frames etc.

```
is.sequence <- function(x, ...)
    UseMethod("is.sequence", x)
is.sequence.default <- function(x, ...){
    FALSE
}
is.sequence.numeric <- function(x, tol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), ...){
    if(anyNA(x) || any(is.infinite(x)) || length(x) <= 1 || diff(x[1:2]) == 0)
        return(FALSE)
    diff(range(diff(x))) <= tol
}
is.sequence.integer <- function(x, ...){
    is.sequence.numeric(x, ...)
}
n <- 1236
#Test:
is.sequence(seq(-3, 5, length.out = n))
# TRUE
is.sequence(seq(5, -3, length.out = n))
# TRUE
is.sequence(seq(3.5, 2.5 + n, length.out = n))
# TRUE
is.sequence(LETTERS[1:7])
```

Basically the implementation checks if the max and min of the differences are exactly equal.

While using the S3 class methods makes the implementation slightly more complicated it simplifies checks for wrong input types, and allows for implementations for other classes. For example this makes it simple to extend this method to say `Date` objects, which would require one to consider if a sequence of only weekdays (or work days) is also a sequence.

## Speed comparison

This implementation is very safe, but using S4 classes adds some overhead. For small length vectors the benefit is the diversity of the implementation, while it is around 15 % slower at worst. For larger vectors it is however slightly faster as shown in the microbenchmark below.

Note that the median time is better for comparison, as the garbage cleaner may add uncertain time to the benchmark.

```
ss <- seq(1, 1e6)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(is.sequential(ss),
                               is.sequence(ss), #Integer calls numeric, adding a bit of overhead
                               is.sequence.numeric(ss))
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr                         min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# is.sequential(ss)       19.47332 20.02534 21.58227 20.45541 21.23700 66.07200   100
# is.sequence(ss)         16.09662 16.65412 20.52511 17.05360 18.23958 61.23029   100
# is.sequence.numeric(ss) 16.00751 16.72907 19.08717 17.01962 17.66150 55.90792   100
```