# Merging datasets when the values of keys are not consistent

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I am trying to merge two data sets, by separate keys, consecutively.

I can't use all three keys at once, because the data has missing values and errors. For example, the first name for someone would be "Mary" in one, and "M" in another.

See this sample data:

```
data1 <- data.frame(name = c("Mary", "John", "Christoper", "Vijay", "Jack", "Clancy"), 
                    company.id = c("3489", "8796", "7283", "9834", "3453", "4354"),
                    passport = c("A74638", NA, "A34679", "A34768", "B34353", "33452"),
                    var1 = c(3, 6, 7, 9, 7, 9), 
                    var2 = c(343, 354, 874, 203, 423, 567), 
                    va3 = c(4545,6767,2345, 6580, NA, 32456)) 


data2 <-  data.frame(name = c("M", "John", "Christoper", "Vij"), 
                     company.id = c("3489", "8796", "7283", NA),
                     passport = c("A74638", "B38746", "A3460", "A34768"),
                     var4 = c("apple", "bannana", "yogh", "shampoo"), 
                     var5 = c(4566, 4562, 7869, 5485))
```

Ideally, I'd use a left join by calling for the three common keys. But in this case, the names don't perfectly match, there are typos in the company.id and missing values, so this does not give me the desired outcome.

```
merged <-
data1 %>% left_join(data2, by = c("name", "company.id", "passport"))
```

This does not work either, because the moment I join it with one dataset, R spews out a different column for the ID's it did not recognize...

```
merged2 <- data1 %>% left_join(data2, by= "name") %>% 
                       left_join(data2, by ="company.id") %>%
                          left_join(data2, by = "passport")
```

Any suggestions to solve this dilemma would be greatly appreciated. This is what I would like it to look like:

```
outcome <- data.frame(name = c("Mary", "John", "Christoper", "Vijay"), 
                      company.id = c("3489", "8796", "7283", "9834"),
                      passport = c("A74638", "B38746", "A34679", "A34768"),
                      var1 = c(3, 6, 7, 9),
                      var2 = c(343, 354, 874, 203),
                      va3 = c(4545,6767,2345, 6580),
                      var4 = c("apple", "bannana", "yogh", "shampoo"), 
                      var5 = c(4566, 4562, 7869, 5485))
```

Note that in my outcome, the missing value for company id has been replaced, the full names are corrected, and the wrong passport number has been ignored and replaced with the correct one!

Thanks for the help!!! :) I would prefer a dplyr solution, but I would take any other advice too!

---

***EDIT***

I was not able to figure out fuzzy_join to accomplish the above output. Here are two possible outcomes, that would be equally useful.

In this case, data1 has fully reliable data in the three matching keys :name, company.id and passport number. So I would want to match data1 to data2...where data2 is the only data set with missing values/typos.

Is there a more straightforward way of solving this?

```
data1 <- data.frame(name = c("Mary", "John", "Christoper", "Vijay", "Jack", "Clancy"), 
                    company.id = c("3489", "8796", "7283", "9834", "3453", "4354"),
                    passport = c("A74638", "B38746", "A34679", "A34768", "B34353", "B33452"),
                    var1 = c("3", "6", "7", "9", "7", "9"), 
                    var2 = c("343", "354", "874", "203", "423", "567"), 
                    var3 = c(4545,6767,2345, 6580, NA, 32456)) 



data2 <-  data.frame(name = c("M", "John", "Christoper", "Vij"), 
                     company.id = c("3489", "8796", "7283", NA),
                     passport = c("A74638", "B38746", "A3460", "A34768"),
                     var4 = c("apple", "bannana", "yogh", "shampoo"), 
                     var5 = c(4566, 4562, 7869, 5485))
```

This is one possible outcome I would want, replacing all the missing, faulty values of data with the correct values of data1.

```
outcome <- data.frame(name = c("Mary", "John", "Christoper", "Vijay"), 
                      company.id = c("3489", "8796", "7283", "9834"),
                      passport = c("A74638", "B38746", "A34679", "A34768"),
                      var1 = c("3", "6", "7", "9"),
                      var2 = c("343", "354", "874", "203"),
                      var3 = c("4545","6767","2345", "6580"),
                      var4 = c("apple", "bannana", "yogh", "shampoo"), 
                      var5 = c(4566, 4562, 7869, 5485))
```

This is another possible outcome; the merged data set does not account for the typos and missing values, but at least I get a completely merged data set....

```
outcome2 <- data.frame(name = c("M", "John", "Christoper", "Vij"), 
                      company.id = c("3489", "8796", "7283", NA),
                      passport = c("A74638", "B38746", "A34679", "A34768"),
                      var1 = c("3", "6", "7", "9"),
                      var2 = c("343", "354", "874", "203"),
                      var3 = c("4545","6767","2345", "6580"),
                      var4 = c("apple", "bannana", "yogh", "shampoo"), 
                      var5 = c(4566, 4562, 7869, 5485))
```

Comment: Take a look at the package `fuzzyjoin`. Also, is it just one of the two tables that has missing values? In your example, all of your typos and missing info are in `data2`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out! Data1 also has missing values, but no typos.

Answer (score 0):

This was getting a bit long for a comment, although I'm afraid it's just a list of ideas rather than a solution. @Marcus's makes an excellent suggestion with `fuzzyjoin`, which should fix a good amount of problems.

My experience with similar datasets is that you may need to create an additional column with truly "unregexable" equivalences, in your case probably `name` (e.g. Bobby for Robert). Hopefully this will be few.

Another strategy to combine or replace with the above is to take a numeric variable that is [meant to be sequential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506848/check-whether-vector-in-r-is-sequential) (`company.id`?) and rely on it as much as possible.

The final point is that they key is your own knowledge of what data is reliable and what isn't. If you are not sure, this may be an impossible task.

Oh, and if you've got spatial information remember there is also `sf::st_join` and others.