# R test if a double is zero in dataframe

Tags: r

How can I best test(and select) if double is "zero". If have tried this:

```
summary(df.1[weights==0,1])
          Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max.       NA's 
    -100880.000      0.000      0.000      1.179      0.000   90993.000      17597
```

But as results are non-zero - something must be wrong.

EDIT 1
I have ensured the colname is correct - but I still get same error:

```
head(df.1)
       weights
1   0.00000
2 -57.09428
3   0.00000
4   0.00000

    summary(df.1[weights==0,1])
              Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max.       NA's 
        -100880.000      0.000      0.000      1.179      0.000   90993.000      17597
```

Comment: You are testing if elements of a vector in your global environment called `weights` are zero, and using this to subset the first column of your `data.frame`. Is this vector the same as the first column?

Comment: @James    Aha! df.1 has LOST it's column names. It was created by df.1<-as.data.frame(df[1:20000,1]). Why did colnames get removed?

Comment: @James - Please see EDIT 1

Comment: @ManInMoon now try `summary(df.1[df.1$weights==0,1])`

Comment: or `with(df.1,summary(weights[weights==0]))` ...

Comment: You sure you're not going to run into machine roundoff?  That is, the usual FAQ about binary representation of floats, and recommendations to test `abs(x) < .Machine.eps^2` instead of zero.

Comment: @Carl - That's useful too I will try and incorporate it as well

Comment: In addition to the solutions given above `summary(subset(df.1,weights==0)[,1])` should also work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if something, say `x`, is zero:

```
isTRUE(all.equal(x, 0))
```

But this doesn't really work with vectors in a way we expect. So let's incorporate [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664017/do-you-reassign-and-to-istrue-all-equal):

```
AlmostEqual <- function(x, y, tolerance=1e-8) {
  diff <- abs(x - y)
  mag <- pmax(abs(x), abs(y))
  ifelse(mag > tolerance, diff/mag <= tolerance, diff <= tolerance)
}
```

Then:

```
subset(df.1, AlmostEqual(df.1$weights, 0))
```